# How to have a Slider in a class view controller that changes the volume of a song playing in the AppDelage, in Objective-C for iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer, uislider

How to have a Slider in a class view controller that changes the volume of a song playing in the AppDelage, in Objective-C for iOS?
Here is my code in the .h AppDelegate

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface JARAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    AVAudioPlayer *musicPlayer;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

- (void)playMusic;
- (void)setVolume:(float)vol;

@end
```

And in the .m:

```
- (void)playMusic
{

    NSString *musicPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"The History of the World" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *musicURL =  [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:musicPath];

    musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicURL error:nil];
    [musicPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];   // Negative number means loop forever
    [musicPlayer setVolume:1.0];

    [musicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [musicPlayer play];
    NSLog(@"play");
}

- (void)setVolume:(float)vol
{
    [musicPlayer setVolume:vol];
}
```

and when 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' I call  `[self playMusic];`
This works and plays the song I want a full volume! Then in a different class called SettingsViewControler:
The .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "JARAppDelegate.h"

@interface JARSettingsViewController : UIViewController
{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *volumeSliderOutlet;

- (IBAction)volumeSliderActoin:(id)sender;

@end
```

The .m:

```
- (IBAction)volumeSliderActoin:(id)sender
{
     NSLog(@"Volume Changed");
     [JARAppDelegate setVolume:sender];
}
```

Volume Changed is logged everytime you move the slider up and down, and so it should be sending setVolume a value between 0.0 and 1.0. But I get an error that says "No known class method for selector 'setVolume:'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are trying to invoke a *class* method when you call:

```
[JARAppDelegate setVolume:sender];
```

but this doesn't exist. You have created an *instance* method.

Try creating a singleton for the AVAudioPlayer, then you could do the following:

```
[[AVAudioPlayer sharedInstance] setVolume:vol];
```

Comment: That's really a different question altogether. Have a read of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern and then search for specific Objective-C implementations.